# How to verify that chrome is working on my Amazon Linux AMI server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux, chromedp

On my server I am using Chromedp (a Go package) that runs a headless version of chrome to generate PDFs for me.

When I run this process on my windows machine it works great. Then when I try to run it on my Amazon Linux AMI server I always get the error message "context cancelled"

I asked on their github page if that was an issue with something I was doing and I was told that it might be happening if the browser crashes or fails to start.

How can I verify that my version of chrome is working through the command line?

I followed [this](https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/) guide when I was installing chrome.

Comment: If all you need to do is generate PDFs, why are you using Chromedp? There are many much more efficient PDF-creation tools.

Comment: I see a problem with the phrase «…I try to run it»—what is "it" here? You cannot run a Go package (it's a library) so you must either be running some Go code which makes use of that package or that "chromedp" thing also provides a program to remote control a headless Chrome installation. In the former case, please show us the relevant code which calls out to chromedp's API, and highlight which line of code fails; in the second case please remove the `go` tag as it's not a question about programming in Go. Thanks.